# How do I get a Rigged 3D Model made in blender to display and animate on the iPhone?

Tags: 3d, iphone, blender

I have a rigged model in blender of a man walking, I would like to know how to get this to display and animate on the iPhone and if their is a good free game library out their that lets me do it (even if it means saving as another format).

I've tried Cocos3D with no luck as the convertor from collada to Pod is crap (for lack of a better word)

Comment: What didn't work in the conversion process? (eg. from Blender to POD)?

Answer (score 1):

There is also the open source Gamekit 
A cross-platform 3D game engine using Ogre or Irrlicht and Bullet for Windows, Linux, Mac, Android and iPhone

http://code.google.com/p/gamekit/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest 3D game engine to use for getting an animated model from Blender onto iPhone is Unity, but that's not free:
http://unity3d.com/unity/editor/importing

The best free option is probably Oolong:
http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/

---

Incidentally, the last time I was working with 3D on iPhone I was using miniB3D, the iOS port of miniB3D, which itself was an OpenGL port of Blitz3D:

https://github.com/si-design/minib3d

Unfortunately while there used to be a good .b3d exporter for Blender, I don't think that works in the latest version of Blender.

Comment: unity is just overrated in my opinion, there are plenty of options out there, also Unity has a really poor support for mobile devices, i have tried it for Android and you can basically customize nothing in the building phase and you get really poor performance. For example there is Ogre that is a complete 3D engine free, opensource and also comes for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend giving [SIO2](http://sio2interactive.com/learningresource.php) a go. 
I've tried it a bit couple of years back with Blender2.4x and it was very easy to get started with.

[image: SIO exporters]